# For loop iterating twice the expected iterations

Tags: c, for-loop

I'm writing a C program which prompts user for a file name and when entered it shows first 20 lines and then wait for the input from user. So, everything worked fine just that it showed 40 lines instead of 20, so I reduced the number of lines to 1 and it showed 2 lines instead. I even tried with while loop instead of for loop but still same result.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    FILE *in;
    char file[81], buffer[81];
    int flag = 1, c, i;

    printf("File: ");
    scanf("%s", file);

    if ((in = fopen (file, "r")) == NULL) {
        printf("Unable to open the file: %s\n", file);
        return 1;
    }

    while (flag) {
        for (i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
            if (fgets (buffer, 80, in) != NULL) {
                printf("%s", buffer);
            } else {
                flag = 0;
            }
        }

        c = getchar();
        if (c == (char) 'q')
            flag = 0;
    }

    fclose (in);

    return 0;
}
```

Problem in C by Stephen G Kochan, Chapter 16, Problem 6

Note: I'm not expecting an alternative method to solve the problem, I just want to know what is causing this problem.

Comment: I don't see anything that counts the number of lines. And what's the purpose of a `for` loop that counts from 1 to 1?

Comment: it loops because `flag` is set only when `fgets` fails. why this flag?

Comment: @Barmar Read the question more closely, that `1` was `20` before ;-)

Comment: @Barmar I just fixed it, it was supposed to be for just one iteration,

Comment: The book has an error. `char file[81]` and you can `fgets(...81...)`.

Comment: `fgets()` already subtracts 1 to allow for the null byte, you don't have to do it yourself.

Comment: the book is better safe than sorry :)

Comment: To clarify: It also shows the 20 (or 2) lines the first time round? Otherwise, I'd say `getchar()` picks up the newline you need to enter to submit the line.

Comment: getchar reads standard input, fgets reads a file, not stdin.

Comment: (or was the error by you)

Comment: @dhke it showes 2 lines of text the first time with this exact code and when i replaced 1 with 20 it shows 40 lines of text.

Comment: @AnkitRGadiya No, I meant `getchar()`. See Jean-François Fabre's below. Your `getchar()` consumes the newline left there after the initial `scanf()`. If you hit enter on the prompt, you should only be getting 10 lines, however if you hit e.g. `<space> <enter>`, you'll be getting 20 lines.

Comment: Aside: in `if (c == (char) 'q')` the `c` and the `'q'` are both of type `int` so no need for any cast.

Comment: @dhke `fgets` does not leave a newline in the input buffer - it reads it and includes it in the string that was read.

Comment: @WeatherVane I never mentioned `fgets()`. The code does a `scanf()` from stdin. After this, there's still a `'\n'`in the input buffer for `stdin`. That gets consumed by the subsequent `getchar()`, skipping the intended pause. There is no interaction with the `fgets()` from the file in this. I missed that part the first time round and though only of `q` `\n` being entered, causing two iterations to run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the issue is that there's a remaining linefeed from your first `scanf("%s", file);` statement that is picked up by your `getchar()` the first time, so the loop runs twice without any user input.

To prevent that, just `getchar()` before your loop.

Aside (as comments noted), `fgets (buffer, 80, in)` needs `buffer[80]` only.

And `scanf("%s", file);` could be protected like `scanf("%80s", file);` (here you need to keep 81 bytes, unlike in `fgets`)

Comment: If scanf call is the problem then why is it happening everything the loop iterates. Each consecutive time the for loop runs it iterates twice as many times not just the first time.
Also, about the getchar() call, i cannot place it before the loop as the problem wants me to first print 20 lines and then prompt user for input, if the user enter 'q', then the program should stop, any other input should result in printing the next 20 lines.

Comment: Because you have `getchar` in the loop. You enter a character that is not `'q'` not just a plain `Enter`? Then there will a newline in the input buffer.

Comment: Okay i got it, I tried hardcoding the file name and thus removing the scanf call and it worked. Obviously not the correct idea though. Thanks